# calendly Iframe Embedded response data

Tags: calendly

I am using these code to load cleanly calendar.

```
Calendly.initPopupWidget({
url: 'https://calendly.com/mojo-customer-experience/renewal-check-in?embed_domain=calendly-embed.com&embed_type=Inline&back=1&month=2020-10',
utm: {}
},false);
```

once user select the date and time, i need to read the scheduling  date and time  web page itself. can you please  help  how to read  scheduling   information

Thanks,

Mani c